# Elasticsearch geospatial queries returning no hits

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, kibana, geospatial

I'm using Kibana to look at a geospatial dataset in Elasticsearch for a feature currently under development. There is a index of positions which contains field "loc.coordinates", which is a geo_point, and has as data as such:

```
loc.coordinates         25.906958000000003, 51.776407000000006
```

However when I run the following query I get no results:

**Query**

```
GET /positions/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "2000km",
                    "loc.coordinates" : {
                        "lat" : 25,
                        "lon" : 51
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "took": 12,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 6,
    "successful": 6,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

I'm trying to understand why this is, as there are over 250,000 datapoints in the index, and I'm getting no hits regardless of how big the search area is. When I look in the position index mapping I see the following:

```
"loc": {
  "type": "nested",
  "properties": {
    "coordinates": {
      "type": "geo_point"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

I'm new to Elasticsearch and have been making my way through the documentation, but so far I don't see why my geo queries aren't working as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `loc` field is of type `nested`, so you need to query that field accordingly with a `nested` query:

```
GET /positions/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : {
                "nested": {
                   "path": "loc",
                   "query": {
                      "geo_distance" : {
                         "distance" : "2000km",
                         "loc.coordinates" : {
                            "lat" : 25,
                            "lon" : 51
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that explains it! Is there any obvious advantage to having this be nested? Looking at the rest of the mapping, it seems unnecessary. Also, currently nothing is showing up in the Visualize > Map visualization when I do a bucket aggregation of loc.coordinates on the vessel_position index, and this must be why.

Comment: If you have a single object, then nested is not necessary (only if you have an array of objects). Also note that nested data types can't be queried in KIbana.